# Where is the "Alternate email address" section in the Google Calendar options?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api

[This](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37135?hl=en&vid=0-441378315427-1485537150491&visit_id=1-636211344784304823-3966805347&rd=1) official Google support page says you can respond to Google Calendar invites from alternative email addresses, if you add them via the "Alternate email address" section of the "edit notifications" calendar options window:
[image: Google calendar "Edit Notifications" page]

But, while I can add the alternative email to Gmail, I don't see a "Alternate email address", in that window. I there an extra step I am missing? Or was that feature removed or moved, and the docs not updated (fairly typical Google move, unfortunately :( )

Comment: Are you using a G Suite account? I don't think it's available elsewhere.

Comment: Nope, not using G Suite. I guess you're right, they must have removed that feature for regular GMail accounts. Nice of them to update their docs to reflect that :(

Comment: I just tried to do add an alternate email as well and the feature is not there as described in their docs here: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37135

Comment: Yeah they removed it, now you have to pay for G-Suite if you want that feature :( Of course they didn't update the docs to reflect that.

Comment: At least in the new G-Cal settings interface, it took a little while (~10 min) for the option to show up, but eventually it did appear under the "General Notifications" section.

Comment: (Arrgh!  I can log in to g calendar with a short email address I signed up for and added to my main google account as an alternate email, but if i accept gCal event invitations sent to it, they DONT show up in my gCalendar. What bad behavior. </rant>). But if i log in to my academic gSuite account I can add the short email address under the "General Notifications" section, i’ll be able to see the events, but how will they appear if i’m logged into both accounts at the same time?  Hmm..

Comment: Under Settings (the gear), I don’t see a "General Notifications" section. Yes, i’m logged  in to my academic gSuite account.

Comment: I’m wondering if a workaround would be to set up a rule that would forward a copy of any calendar invitations to the short email to my main gmail. Would they then show up in my main calendar? Anyone tried?  Maybe i’ll try if waiting 10+ minutes doesn’t help.

Answer (score 0):

Before looking for the option, make sure that you've added the alternative email address.

To do so, go to Accounts.google.com > "Personal Info" > [Email (or just click here)](https://myaccount.google.com/email). Then edit the information in the "Alternate Emails" section. Make sure to respond to the confirmation email sent to the alternate email.

[image: Google My Account screenshot]

Once you've done that, you'll need to wait a few hours to a couple of days. Eventually, the option will appear under `Settings for my calendars` > `Other notifications` in Google Calendar.

[image: screenshot of Google calendar settings]

Having the alternate email on your google account will allow you to accept google calendar invites that are sent to the alternate non-Gmail account.

Comment: OP asks how to use alternate emails in Google Calendar, not how to create an alternate email.

Comment: @Guillaume this is the answer to the OP question. See my update above.